# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '' when reading file

Tags: python

I'm trying to read each line text file with a single number on each line and convert the number into a list of integers. The test file I wrote contains these numbers:

```
1
23
567
4000
```

I use this code in my main function to read the file and write the output of my function est() into another output file.

```
with open(in_path, "r", encoding = "utf-8") as f_in, \
        open(out_path, "w", encoding = "utf-8") as f_out:
            for line in f_in:
                word1 = est(line)
                f_out.write(f"{line} = {est(line)}")
```

The error occurs when I pass the line to est() as the argument num to convert the string into the list of integers in est().

```
for i in num:
    num_list.append(int(float(i)))
```

This causes the error ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

Comment: You should try to print out what `i` is in the for loop, i'm guessing python is also reading in the carriage return i.e. `\n` which is causing the casting issue.

Comment: @JasonGerard it printed out a blank line but when I do print(num) it prints out 1

Comment: ...since you later iterate num directly, so `float("\n")` fails.  replace `line` with `line.strip()`. Incidentally you call est twice, but save the result in `word1` the first time, making the second call redundant

Comment: @2e0byo that fixed it!  I had already removed word1 I just forgot to edit it in the question. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments:

```py
with open(in_path, "r", encoding = "utf-8") as f_in, \
        open(out_path, "w", encoding = "utf-8") as f_out:
            for line in f_in:
                line = line.strip():
                if not line:
                    continue
                word1 = est(line)
                f_out.write(f"{line} = {word1}")
```

Should work.  Here we skip blank lines, and whitespace on the line.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to strip line first:

```
with open(in_path, "r", encoding = "utf-8") as f_in, \
    open(out_path, "w", encoding = "utf-8") as f_out:
        for line in f_in:
            word1 = est(line.strip())
            f_out.write(f"{line} = {est(line)}")
```